# How to add action to a label without using objective-c in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, parameter-passing, swift4

Objective-C functions

```
@objc func handleTapHash(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("ViewerOfHash"), object: nil)



    }
@objc func ViewerOfHash() {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewerOfHash", sender: nil)

        PassDataController.addData(newData: "12300")
        MainVC.tof = 1

    }
```

Add action to label(hashTag.hashTag1)

```
let gestureRecognizer1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTapHash))
hashTag.hashTag1.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer1)
```

It works, but I don't want to use objective-c and NS functions.

There is a label that send some data to another page in my code.

How can I change my code to Swift4 fully?

Comment: Anytime you use a target/action you have no choice. It's due to the original Objective-C implementation of the framework being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `@objc` is required because you're using `Selectors` in `target:action:`. The ObjC runtime is required in order to lookup the method implementation for a given `Selector`.